Flask-restx with both payload and query params
I have an API put() call that that requires path-params, query-params and a JSON payload. For various reasons, we are not modelling the entire payload, we just want a modelled outer-JSON-envelope, and using fields.Raw() without subclassing allows this to work.

The problem is how to use @api.expect() to specify both the payload and a query-param parser.
The code fragment below shows our current method - specify the query param(s) with a .doc() decorator on the class, then specify payload params with a .expect() decorator on the put() call. Everything else I've tried causes Swagger not to display one of the parameters.

My question is: is this split method the correct way to achieve this, or is there a way of rolling both parameter types into a single .expect() call?

class WBRTRoutes():

    @staticmethod
    def bind(api):
        # create a namespace
        ns_workareas = api.namespace("workareas", description = "Registered workareas")
            
        # create a model for a wrapped "agnostic" payload 
        # I just want to model the wrapper, not the detailed content
        mod_workarea_update = api.model("WorkareaUpdate", {
            "workarea":  fields.Raw(description = "the workarea object")
            })

        # create a model for "internal" response content - a list of strings
        mod_details = api.model("Details", {
            "details": fields.List(fields.String)
            })

        # for consisitency between calls, all returned responses are wrapped in a message/data envelope
        resp_version = api.model("RspVersion", {
            "message":   fields.String(description = "used to return message to the caller"),
            "data":      fields.Nested(mod_version, description = "the incremented version after an update", skip_none = True)
            })
            
        # create a non-parser params dict (instead of more common RequestParser)
        userid_route_params = {
            'workid' : 'The internal workarea identifier'
            }

        # there is a also a path param, which we specify in the .route decorator
        @ns_workareas.route('/<workid>')
        @api.doc(
          description='Represents a registered workarea by its workid',
          # MUST SPECIFY QUERY PARAMS HERE (USING SIMPLE DICT) IF PAYLOAD PARAMS ALSO EXPECTED
          params=userid_route_params)
        class Workarea(Resource):
            # CANNOT SPECIFY QUERY PARAMS HERE (USING PARSER) IF PAYLOAD PARAMS ALSO EXPECTED
            @api.expect(mod_workarea_update, validate=True)
            @api.marshal_with(resp_version)
            @api.response(200, 'Success')
            @api.response(403, 'Forbidden')
            @api.response(404, 'Resource not found')
            def put(self, workid):
                """Performs an undoable update to current a workarea, after checking for interleaved updates"""
                pass



After posting the question, I have learned that it is possible to specify multiple models to @api.expect(), as separate arguments.
I still do not understand the overlap between @api.doc(...,params=) and @api.expect(), but that can wait for another day.
@api.expect(WBRTModels.mod_workarea_update, WBRTParsers.args_update, validate=True)

